# What is the coefficient of $x^6$ in the development of $A$?

Tags: combinatorics

> What is the coefficient of $x^6$ in the development of $A$, where $A=(x^2-3x-1)^4$.

Comment: Have you tried just multiplying it out?  What did you get?

Comment: Actually , we need to solve it using binomial theorem

Comment: I've made a mistake while editing. $A = (x^2-3x-1)^4$, not $2$.

Comment: Yep, I din't noticed that thanks. I've fixed it.

Comment: If you are required to use the binomial theorem, you should put that in your question.  Have you looked up the theorem?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new edit,  the answer is the sum over all contributions, which are $\binom{4}{3}(x^2)^3(-1)$ and $\binom{4}{2}(x^2)^2(-3x)^2(-1)^2$, giving $-4+54=50$.

Comment: Well , yeah we need $(x²)³$ to make $x⁶$ but the coefficient is not 1 nor 4 i found 54 and my teacher found 50.

Comment: Back when it was a square, the answer would be $0$ as there was no $x^6$ term

Comment: What about $(x^2)^2(-3x)^2$?

Comment: Yeah , sorry my bad.

Comment: Well , I still think my teacher is wrong cause what you said is also what i did and it gives me 54

Comment: @BenAbderrahmene: No, look at the update.

Comment: @AlexR hi can I ask you a question when $(x²)³$  wouldn't it be multiplied by $-3x-1$ (I didn't understand where -1 came from) ,so it wouldn't be -4 in the final sum ?

Comment: @BenAbderrahmene: The total parenthetical is raised to the 4'th power, meaning that every term in the expansion (before grouping like-powers) is determined by choosing 4 terms from the parenthetical, with replacement. So we chose $x^2$ 3 times and $-1$ is chosen once. Contrast this with $(x^2)^4$ which won't have a $(-1)$ term since all 4 powers were used up. See Bernard's multinomial answer for the fact that the powers must sum to 4.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You can use the `multinomial formula`: as the expansion is
$$\sum_{\substack{i,j,k\: \text{ s. t.}\\i+j+k=4}}\!\!\!\frac{4!}{i!\,j!\,k!}(x^2)^i(-3x)^j(-1)^k,$$
the coefficient will be
$$\sum_{\substack{i,j,k\: \text{ s. t.}\\i+j+k=4}}\!\!\!\frac{4!}{i!\,j!\,k!}(-1)^{j+k}3^{\mkern 1mu j}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You want binomial, here's binomial.  Write $A$ as 
$$((x^2-3x)-1)^4 = (x^2-3x)^4 - 4 (x^2-3x)^3 + 6 (x^2-3x)^2 - 4 (x^2-3x) + 1 $$
Coefficient of $x^6$ in $(x^2-3x)^4 = x^4 (x-3)^4$ is coefficient of $x^2$ in $(x-3)^4$
is $6 (-3)^2 = 54$.

Coefficient of $x^6$ in $-4(x^2-3x)^3$ is $-4$.

Coefficients of $x^6$ in the other terms are $0$.

So the result is $54-4=50$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=1/y$ and multiply the resulting equation by $y^8$ to get

$$ g(y) = (1-3y-y^2)^4$$

Note that the coefficient of $x^6$ in the original equation is the coefficient of $y^2$ in the new equation.

The coefficient of $y^2$ is the new equation esily found by $$g'' (0)/2 =100/2 =50 $$